# Android: how to find SQLITE_MAX_COMPOUND_SELECT

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

Is there a way to get the value of [`SQLITE_MAX_COMPOUND_SELECT`](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) of a SQLite database on Android?  In the C sqlite3 API, this is `sqlite3_limit(db, SQLITE_LIMIT_COMPOUND_SELECT, -1)`, but I don't see this interface exposed in the [Android SQLite API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

The reason for this is that I'm inserting thousands of rows, and issuing a batch INSERT statement is faster than many single-row inserts, even when it's wrapped in a transaction.  But the max number of rows that can be inserted per statement is limited by `SQLITE_MAX_COMPOUND_SELECT`, necessitating splitting it into several batches.  And, for obvious reasons, I'd rather not hardcode the default limit of 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SQLITE_LIMIT_COMPOUND_SELECT` limit is not a means to prevent memory overflow (as least on Android systems), but just a sanity check.
Therefore, it is extremely unlikely that a vendor will *reduce* it from its default, so 500 should be safe.

Furthermore, as the number of inserted records in one command gets larger, the *incremental* speedup will get smaller; e.g., the speedup of going from 5 to 50 records will be larger than the speedup of going from 50 to 500.
Therefore, just using 50 should not hurt too much.

---

Another way to speed up repeated executions is to use prepared statements, with [`SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Those are all good points.  Hardcoding the value seems pretty safe in this situation, and using a batch size that's well below that should be sufficient for performance.  I'll leave this open for a while in case somebody knows a way to get the values at runtime after all.