# SQLite too many terms in compound SELECT

Tags: android, sqlite

In my Android SQLite databese query I have an INSERT INTO statement followed by about 600 ('data1'),('data2')...  tags, generated by code.

After db.exec(sql) I got this error: "too many terms in compound SELECT (code1); while compiling INSERT INTO.. "

Is there any way to increase this limitation?

Comment: Can you paste your code, where you insert those records.

Comment: You need to reduce the number of terms in your SELECT statement,  
break your insertion into parts with about 500 records

Comment: Instead of calling db.exec just once, do it for every record.

Comment: public static void insertTableData(String[] values, int index){ // values are given as (valu1,value2,...)
sql="INSERT INTO table (field1,field2...) VALUES ";
for (int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
sql+=values[i]+",";  
}

Answer (score 9):

The limit `SQLITE_MAX_COMPOUND_SELECT` [cannot be raised at runtime](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html),

So you need to split your inserts into batches of 500 rows each.  This will be more efficient than inserting one row per query. For e.g.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO tablename (data1,data2) VALUES ("data1","data2")
INSERT INTO tablename (data1,data2) VALUES ("data1","data2")
INSERT INTO tablename (data1,data2) VALUES ("data1","data2")
...
END TRANSACTION
```

Also see [Insert Multiple Rows in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613377/insert-multiple-rows-in-sqlite-error-error-code-1)

Comment: How can check the value of SQLITE_MAX_COMPOUND_SELECT ?

Comment: @user3864532 see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264108/android-how-to-find-sqlite-max-compound-select

Comment: wow, Great answer i struggled to insert for 2 day. Inserting 500 set is really fast.